# Odd C/C++ initialization syntax for integral type variable

Tags: c++, c, compilation

The following snippet compiles perfectly with C/C++ compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = {5};         //<-- why this compiles?
    printf("x = %d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `5`.
`x` is initialized here in a compound-type form although it's of integral type. I would like to understand what conversions are made here and why.

Comment: This means "initialize the first thing to 5". Since there is only one thing, this works as expected.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Reference? And why?

Comment: this kind of declaration we generally do: `char s[10] = {"hello"};`, you can remove `{}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C allows it in:

> (C99, 6.7.8p11) "The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces."

C++ has a similar rule in C++11, 8.5.4p1

Comment: Nice, didn't know it. And what about C++? I also got it compiled with non-C99 compiler: http://ideone.com/aWsjAd

Comment: Got you, also found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267277/where-can-we-use-list-initialization

Comment: C++ also has this rule since the beginning, in C++98 it was written: 8.5p13: *"If T is a scalar type, then a declaration of the form T x = { a }; is equivalent to T x = a;"*

Comment: But why on earth to allow such a thing?.. I see no benefits, just ambiguity

Comment: @icepack maybe to codify an existing (pre-C89) practice

Answer (score 3):

There is no convertions made here, it is standard defined way of variable initialisation.

> ### 8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]
>
> 1 List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list. Such an initializer is called an initializer list, and the comma-separated initializer-clauses of the list are called the elements of the initializer list. An initializer list may be empty. List-initialization can occur in direct-initialization or copy- initialization contexts; list-initialization in a direct-initialization context is called direct-list-initialization and list-initialization in a copy-initialization context is called copy-list-initialization.
>   [Note: List-initialization can be used
>   — as the initializer in a variable definition (8.5)
>   ...
>   [ Example:
>   int a = {1};