# passing a array varaible to function to return a array variable

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to pass array to function (*getcreditcurve). I am expecting function (*getcreditcurve) to return an array. Main function is expected to send several such array to function (*getcreditcurve), pointer function is expected to return a array to main function for different array using the logic given in pointer function (*getcreditcurve). however I get following error. Can somebody help in trouble shooting please? Sorry I went through other post/question in this site but not able to get simplest way to solve this issue. I am going to use this logic to build other projects so simplified the question just to resolve main issue.

```
'#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
typedef double S1[5];
using namespace std;
double *getcreditcurve(double);

int main()
{
S1 C1, C2;

C1 = { 0.0029, 0.0039, 0.0046, 0.0052, 0.0057 };
C2 = { 0.0020, 0.0050, 0.0060, 0.0070, 0.0080 };

typedef double *issuer;
issuer I1 = getcreditcurve(C1);
issuer I2 = getcreditcurve(C2);


ofstream print;
print.open("result1.xls");
print << I1+1 << '\t' << I2+2 << endl;
print.close();
return 0;
}

double *getcreditcurve(double S1[5])
   {
const int cp = 5;
typedef double curve[cp];
curve h;

h[0] = 2 * S1[0];
h[1] = 3 * S1[1];
h[2] = 4 * S1[2];
h[3] = 5 * S1[3];
h[4] = 6 * S1[4];

return h;
 }'
```

1>------ Build started: Project: Project2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\kdatta\documents\cqf\c++\project2\source.cpp(12): error C3079: an initializer-list cannot be used as the right operand of this assignment operator
1>c:\users\kdatta\documents\cqf\c++\project2\source.cpp(13): error C3079: an initializer-list cannot be used as the right operand of this assignment operator
1>c:\users\kdatta\documents\cqf\c++\project2\source.cpp(16): error C2664: 'double *getcreditcurve(double)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'S1' to 'double'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>c:\users\kdatta\documents\cqf\c++\project2\source.cpp(17): error C2664: 'double *getcreditcurve(double)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'S1' to 'double'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>c:\users\kdatta\documents\cqf\c++\project2\source.cpp(42): warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Here I go again - do summat with the indenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
issuer I1 = getcreditcurve(C1);
```

getcreditcurve takes double pointer as an argument but in declaration you only mentioned double..new declaration will be

```
double *getcreditcurve(S1); or double *getcreditcurve(double *)
```

and definition would be

```
double *getcreditcurve(S1 ptr)
{
 const int cp = 5;
 typedef double curve[cp];
 curve h;

 h[0] = 2 * ptr[0];
 h[1] = 3 * ptr[1];
 h[2] = 4 * ptr[2];
 h[3] = 5 * ptr[3];
 h[4] = 6 * ptr[4];

 return h;
}'
```

Comment: @rakeb.void. Thanks for quick response to both of you. I changed my program as per both of your advice. However I don't get desired out put in excel. I expect I+1 to by 3 *0.0039 = 0.0117 and I+2 to 4* 0.0060 = 0.0024 don't see that I don't see any error also in debug. Can you please help

Answer (score 1):

The forward declaration is

```
double *getcreditcurve(double);
```

whereas in the function implementation you wrote

```
double *getcreditcurve(double S1[5])
```

which means

```
double *getcreditcurve(double *);
```

change forward declaration as:

```
double *getcreditcurve(double *);
```

Change `C1` and `C2` initialization as following:

```
S1 C1 = { 0.0029, 0.0039, 0.0046, 0.0052, 0.0057 };
S1 C2 = { 0.0020, 0.0050, 0.0060, 0.0070, 0.0080 };
```

instead of `S1 C1, C2`;

Read [Where can we use list initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267277/where-can-we-use-list-initialization) to know why.

Warning! you are returning a local variable

```
curve h;
```

Make it `static` or change your logic.

[Run Live](http://ideone.com/DNHtjr).